# Image toolbar is not displaying using ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document in Angular 17

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

Image toolbar is not displyaing after uploading the image using ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document latest version 41.2.0 in Angular 17

I have tried by adding below toolbar but it's not working

image: {
toolbar: [
'imageStyle:inline',
'imageStyle:block',
'imageStyle:side',
'|',
'toggleImageCaption',
'imageTextAlternative'
]
}

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "41.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine": "41.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "41.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog": "41.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "41.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "41.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "41.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "7.0.1"
```

Image toolbar should be display without an issue